# Terraform filter_suffix multiple values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Using aws and terraform is it possible to add multiple values to the filtersuffix looking at the documentation they have an example here

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"

  topic {
    topic_arn     = "${aws_sns_topic.topic.arn}"
    events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_suffix = ".dcm"
```

}

I have tried
`filter_suffix = [".dcm",".DCM"]`

With no success

Comment: is that possible in the aws console?

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

I see multiple filter rules, but if you add two suffixs it is invalid due to overlap.

Comment: I looked at the link, but in the section where there are multiple filter rules I can only see two filter rules: one for prefix and one for suffix. Not multiple rules for suffixes

Comment: "The following notification configuration is invalid because it has overlapping suffixes. Two suffixes are considered overlapping if a given string can end with both suffixes. A string can end with jpg and pg so the suffixes are overlapping." looks like it is not doable = (

Comment: You can always add two notifications if you need multiple suffixes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compile the comments into an answer:

It is not possible to have multiple prefixes or suffixes per s3 bucket notification. This is not specific to terraform, as it is also not possible in the AWS management console. A workaround is to define multiple notifcations.